# Гексагональная сетка для google map

Tags: google-maps, карты

Привет, кто сталкивался с добавлением гексагональной сетки для google карт?
Вот такую сетку нужно добавить на всю ширину карты, которая вмещается в экран:

[image: сетка]

Comment: Вообще-то не понял, что требуется получить в результате.

Comment: в результате требуется получить координаты точек, относительно google карты (их должно быть 6. И каждая точка имеет долготу и широту (lat, lng))

Comment: нужно вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677889/tiling-contiguous-polygons-in-google-maps . Но тут расчеты неправильные

Comment: Там же пишут что у вас не получится так сделать потому что на гугл-картах проекция Меркатора. Сетка не будет прямой и красивой на всех масштабах.

Comment: А если эту проекцию учесть в вычисления?

Comment: Если учесть, то сетка не будет прямой и красивой на всех масштабах. Будет натянута на шар как бы.

Answer (score 3):

#### Идея вкратце

Упрощённо говоря, Google Maps – это всего лишь слой в HTML, который обрабатывает действия пользователя и на их основе манипулирует содержимым карты (по большей части изображениями).

Ничего не мешает наложить поверх этого свой HTML слой с любым содержанием. Напротив, разработчики карт к этому и призывают, предоставляя функционал для преобразования географических координат к координатам внутри этого слоя (и больше ничего существенного не дают).

Поэтому наложить можно вообще что угодно, главное – чтобы это было полезно и удобно в рамках Вашей задачи.

---

#### Нюансы

Вы действительно указали очень мало деталей. Например, зачем Вам это? Помимо любопытства это важно для ответа, из области применения вытекают важные моменты. Как минимум, у меня есть такие вопросы:

1. Должна ли эта сетка быть привязана ко всему земному шару или только к каким-то регионам, с которыми Вы планируете работать? Варианты: **глобус** / **регион**.
   <sub>На мой взгляд, фраза *"на всю ширину карты, которая вмещается в экран"* не совсем отвечает на этот вопрос.</sub>
2. Нужно ли Вам учитывать проекцию Меркатор? (Как [упомянул @sanmai](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/782029/198251)) Варианты: **Меркатор** / **не Меркатор**.
3. Нужна ли Вам эта сетка с фиксированным масштабом, или же при приближении она должна увеличиваться и разделяться на более мелкие шестиугольники? Варианты: **фикс** / **раздел**.
4. Должно ли быть какое-то взаимодействие с этими шестиугольниками? Должны ли они отображать цвета, текст? Варианты: **взаимод** / **без взаимод**.
5. С технической стороны, как лучше реализовать наложение на Гугл-карты для Вашей задачи? По большей части, ответ на этот вопрос вытекает из ответов на предыдущие. Варианты: **картинка** / **холст canvas**  или **svg**.

Некоторое время назад я разрабатывал библиотеку GMapsTable для наложения таблицы на Google Maps ([описание на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/330920/)), и могу сказать, что в любом случае это весьма непростая задача. В качестве наложения я использовал таблицу, так как шестиугольники мне не были нужны, а Меркатор не учитывался (данные не по глобусу, а регионам, искажения слабо заметны). Также, в таблицу легко добавлять текст (простым HTML) или взаимодействие (можно наляпать JS события отдельным ячейкам).

---

#### Предлагаемые варианты решения

В зависимости от комбинаций ответов:

- **фикс**, **без взаимод** – можно взять любую PNG картинку с сеткой и наложить на нужный участок карты. Это не зависит от проекции (Меркатор или нет) и от местоположения (глобус или регион), просто нужно подобрать / сгенерировать оптимально подходящее изображение. Довольно лёгкий, но на столько же мало функциональный способ.
- В большинстве остальных случаев я бы использовал холст или svg. Это сложно, особенно если погнаться за точностью, красотой, плавностью, зато возможности ничем не ограничены.

  Вне зависимости от **фикс** / **раздел** лучше задать готовый массив точек, а не вычислять всё в коде. Если нужны **раздел**яющиеся шестиугольники, это также проще реализовать на основе имеющихся начальных вершин. В таком случае задача сводится всего лишь к созданию этого набора точек и алгоритма для их отрисовки, преобразования шестиугольников к координатам на экране.

  Вывод текста и цветов в таком случае относительно лёгок. Если нужно **взаимодействие**, то можно просто перехватывать событие клика и реализовать функцию обратного преобразования: от координаты на экране к конкретному шестиугольнику.

  *Как создать набор исходных точек?* Например, можно банально взять одну из картинок с шестиугольниками (Меркатор или нет, на Ваш выбор) и вручную или с кодом перевести все вершины в координаты широты/долготы. Можно составить их в отдельные объекты шестиугольников или же просто отдельно прописать линии между точками, если работы с шестиугольниками не планируется. Муторно, но альтернатива не проще: написать код для генерации сферы с поверхностью из шестиугольников и перевода этих же вершин, линий / шестиугольников в координаты карты.

---

**Полезные ссылки:**

- [Google Maps API: собственные наложения на карту](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays?hl=ru) – простой пример с наложением картинки.
- [Исходный код GMapsTable](https://github.com/AivanF/GMapsTable/blob/master/gmapstable.js) – большой пример с динамическим наложением табицы.

Comment: Здравствуйте. спасибо за ответ. Я отвечу на ваши вопросы

Comment: 1. Планирую работать с регионом, но задача такова, что нужно выгрузить все координаты хексов относительно карты.

Comment: 2. проекцию меркатор цчитывать нужно

Comment: 3. сетка должна быть динамическая. при зуме должно быть определенное число хексов

Comment: 4. взаимодействие будет. при клике на хекс, увеличивается масштаб и показывается определенные точки в данном хексе. плюс при наведении на хекс отображается текст с иконкой

Comment: Боюсь, что это обсуждение может сильно разрастись, в комментариях это не особо удобно. Предлагаю перейти в любую среду для общения 1на1.

Comment: @ВячеславКурилов не уверен, что приглашение дошло. На всякий случай Skype: aivan_f Telegram: https://t.me/aivanf

Answer (score 2):

Прямо так, как вы хотите, у вас не получится так сделать на всех увеличениях потому что на Гугл-картах используется проекция Меркатора. Это значит ближе к полюсам ваша сетка будет искажена, будто бы натянута на шар. Примерный вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Картинка отсюда.](https://www.feartheboot.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24486&start=10)

Comment: А подскажите пож. каким образом тогда можно выгрузить все координаты хексов с координатами относительно гугл карты?

Comment: Любая наложенная сетка не будет искажена, так как Google карты не обрабатывают наложения какой-либо проекцией. Она создаются поверх уже готовой карты как отдельный HTML элемент, поэтому автору вопроса ничто не мешает вставить сетку шестигранников "прямо так"; более того, для этого существуют множество способов.

Comment: @AivanF. напишите свой ответ, что за проблема?